# Is it 'Search Kit', 'SearchKit', 'Search-Kit', 'search kit'? 'Form Builder', 'FormBuilder', 'Form-Builder', 'afform'?

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder

Questions and answers here on StackExchange and in the CiviCRM UI and documentation refer to these tools in various ways.

What is the preferred way to refer to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are standardising on camelcase format, so the preferred names are:

- **SearchKit**

and

- **FormBuilder**

References to these in the CiviCRM interface and documentation are being updated where necessary.

('Afform' was the original working name for FormBuilder.)